# post data using ajax and js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Every time i try to use my classes below to post the array i made (also below) the `ajax` request doesn't pass the input as `$_POST` values but as `$_REQUEST` values seen in the web address bar at the top of the screen. I'm very new to `Ajax` and javascript (only been working with it about a month) so any tips and trick to fix anything below is greatly appreciated.

```
var formErrors=["Passage","FirstName","Zip"];
var formInput=["EventID","Passage","FirstName","LastName","Email","Organization","Location","Zip"];
```

#### Head of HTML

```
    $(function () {
        $("#signUp").click(function() {
            if(formArrayValidation(formErrors) != false) {      
                formPostAjax(formInput, 'join-event.php');
            }
            return false;                   
        });          
     });
```

#### Basics.js

```
formArrayValidation = function(errorArray) {
for(var i = 0; i < errorArray.length; i++) {
    $('.error').hide();  
    var name = $("input#" + errorArray[i]).val();  
    if (name == "") {  
        $("label#" + errorArray[i] + "_error").show();  
        $("input#" + errorArray[i]).focus();  
        return false;
    }
}
}
formPostAjax = function(inputArray, form) {
var dataString = "";
for(var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++)
{
    var data = inputArray[i];
    var dataInput = $("input#" + data).val();
    if(i = 0) {
        dataString = dataString + data + '=' + dataInput;
    }
    else {
        dataString = dataString + '&' + data + '=' + dataInput;
    }
}
$.ajax ({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: form,  
    data: dataString,  
    success: function() { 
    } 
}); 
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a `REQUEST` request, so `$_REQUEST` is just a PHP constructed superglobal that joins POST and GET requests (and other types as well) for convenience, so if your data is in `$_REQUEST`, it's probably in either `$_POST` or `$_GET` as well, and probably the first one as it's a POST request.

Comment: I'll take a wild guess, if the adress bar changes, and a querystring is appearing in the adressbar, the form is submitted, and you have javascript errors that makes the return false in your event handler not work. Open the console in the browser (F12) and check for errors.

Comment: @adeneo I have opened the console and there was no errors with this part of the code. I thought that too when I was trying to figure it out. I watched the call stack and stepped into everything. No problems from what I can tell. Yes what you said above is correct. _join-an-event.php?EventID=1&Passage=Gen+1-3&FirstName=Jane&LastName=Doe&Email=JaneDoe%40gmail.com&Organization=Spice+Doe&Location=Arnold&Zip=15401&Accept=on_ is what i get when i submit the form with appropriate information. could the Accept=on be effecting it? I have a check box that enables the submit button and it's posting too.

Comment: What do you mean "this part of the code", any error would halt the execution of your javascript, is the console clean.

Comment: Yes i understand that it will break if that were the case but i have the code above implemented on 2 diffrent pages one that is displaying an error with my calander.js for date fields and one that isn't showing an error because calander.js isn't included in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your event listener should be on the form and it should be:

`$('#form_identifier').submit(...);`

Additionally, jQuery provides a nice shortcut method for serializing form data:

```
$('#form_identifier').submit(function(){
   var post_data = $(this).serialize()
   // ....
   return false;
});
```

Comment: I just tested that and I was wrong, correcting my post. Thanks for pointing this out.